# Testes de Web Service com Arquillian

Tags: java, web-service, tdd, cdi, glassfish

Estou fazendo uma classe de teste unitário e estou usando Arquillian por causa do CDI, neste casso estou testando um Web Service para autenticação de usuários da empresa. Segue a fonte da classe de teste:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class UsuarioWebServiceTest {

/**
 * Criando o arquivo de deploy do arquillian.
 * 
 * @return JavaArchive
 */
@Deployment
public static WebArchive createTestArchive() {
    return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "consisanet-aut-web.war")
            .addPackages(true, Usuario.class.getPackage())
            .addPackages(true, UsuarioDAO.class.getPackage())
        .addPackages(true, JPAUsuarioDAOImpl.class.getPackage())
            .addPackages(true, UsuarioWebService.class.getPackage())
            .addAsResource("test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
            .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml")
            .addAsWebInfResource("sun-jaxws.xml")
            .setWebXML("web.xml");
}

/**
 * UsuarioWebServiceService.
 */
private static UsuarioWebServiceService service;

/**
 * Método responsável pela configuração da classe de teste.
 */
@BeforeClass
public static void setup() {
    service = new UsuarioWebServiceService();
}

/**
 * Método responsável por testar webservice de usuários.
 */
@Test
public void testeUsuarioAutenticacao() {
    Usuario usuario = service.getUsuarioWebServicePort().autenticarUsuario("55550001", "senha");

    Assert.assertNotNull(usuario);
}

/**
 * Método responsável por testar método do webservice que retornar o perfil do usuário pelo seu identificador.
 */
@Test
public void testeUsuarioConsultaPerfil() {
    Usuario usuario = service.getUsuarioWebServicePort().consultarUsuario("99202931");

    Assert.assertNotNull(usuario);
}

/**
 * Método responsável por testar o método que retorna uma lista de usuários pelo seu grupo.
 */
@Test
public void testeUsuarioConsultaGrupo() {
    int grupousuarioAdiministrador = 1;
    Usuario[] usuarios = service.getUsuarioWebServicePort().consultarUsuariosPorGrupo(grupousuarioAdiministrador);
    System.out.println(usuarios.length);
    Assert.assertNotNull(usuarios);
}
```

Ate aí tudo bem, o teste roda, o Web Service é chamado e dá a resposta que eu esperava. Mas após cada método de teste ser executado, o seguinte `stacktrace` é impresso:

```
Advertência: Error invoking requestDestroyed method on ServletRequestListener org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: A request must be associated with the context in order to load the known conversations
at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractConversationContext.getCurrentConversation(AbstractConversationContext.java:390)
at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationContextActivator.deactivateConversationContext(ConversationContextActivator.java:148)
at org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldListener.requestDestroyed(WeldListener.java:143)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.fireRequestDestroyedEvent(StandardContext.java:5261)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.postInvoke(StandardHostValve.java:255)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:359)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

E aqui, minhas dependências do Arquillian

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.CR6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.CR4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
    <version>4.0-b83</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Quais as versões do Arquillian e do Weld?

Comment: editei minha  pergunta para adicionar as informações sobre as versões do projeto como você pediu, quando ao weld não é especificado ele como dependencia, o que fale é o do glassfish mesmo, no caso uso glassfish 4

Comment: Fiz várias pesquisas e não encontrei nada sólido sobre o erro, a não ser bugs em versões específicas do Weld. Vi na versão GUJ da pergunta que você tentou atualizar e ocorreram outros erros. Talvez seja o caso de atualizar "só um pouquinho", ou seja, ao invés de tentar colocar a última versão, selecionar uma ou duas releases depois da sua. O ideal seria ter a última versão e resolver esses problemas que ocorreram. Em último caso crie um projeto simples para reproduzir o erro e adicione no *bug tracker* da ferramenta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver este problema, precisei apenas atualizar as versões do arquillian e como o utluiz falou atualizar so um pouquinho, vou postar as minhas dependencias para voces verem como elas ficaram

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <version>${version.arquillian}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1</artifactId>
        <version>${version.arquillian-glassfish-embedded}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
        <version>${version.glassfish}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

e aqui as versões das dependencias que eu usei

```
<junit.version>4.10</junit.version>
<version.glassfish>4.0</version.glassfish>
<version.arquillian>1.0.0.Final</version.arquillian>
<version.arquillian-glassfish-embedded>1.0.0.CR4</version.arquillian-glassfish-embedded>
```

obrigado a todos que se emprenharam para me ajudar, obrigado